# How to specify the same templated member function for multiple class types in c++?

Tags: c++, function, templates, macros

In an effort to avoid a lot of typing, I would like to define a function once for multiple classes.  My hope is that the template system would provide the definition to each of them.  I suppose a non-trivial macro could accomplish this also, but they seems to be much less preferred.  I do not wish to use inheritance where I could create a base class for S1,S2, due to its complications.

```
struct S1 {
    bool print(int i);
};

struct S2 {
    bool print(int i);
};

// bool S1::print(int i) { i=+1; std::cout<<i; return true; } NOTE: this is the line I don't want to type many times for each S*

template< typename T >
bool  T::print(int i) { i=+1; std::cout<<i; return true; }  // TODO

int main() {
S1 s1 {};
s1.print( 5 );
}
```

Comment: Can we assume `print` is much more complicated in real life? At the moment it doesn't do much and to make a good suggestion on how best to get what you want (because you can't do what you are attempting) I think we're going to need a few more details.

Comment: The line you show that you don't want to repeat (`bool S1::print(int i) { i=1; return true; }`) does not make much sense. Assigning a value to a parameter and not using it is useless. Also if you print the same text, then why would you have 2 functions to start with? And why would you use template if the function body is not affected by the type of the template?

Comment: @Phil1970, thanks for your reply, however, please presume that the functions are doing different things.  I tried to simplify the example for brevity, and varied some aspects to be sure what I needed would be covered, ie. different classes that have functions that take parameters.

Comment: @HWalters, thanks for your "constructive criticism" but I don't understand your post fully, nor do I know how to clarify/improve the question based on it.  What words should I edit and with what text?

Comment: Perhaps the answer is that what I want to do, cannot be done with templates.  But that is why I asked the question.

Comment: @user4581301, in fact what I want to do is just that simple, perhaps to print i, but that was meant to be implied.  I was trying to be brief, too brief perhaps.

Comment: Tell me exactly why inheritance doesn't suit your needs, given: (1) inheritance as mix-in (what's in both answers so far) makes things like `s1.print( 5 )` syntactically work, call your function, and saves typing. (2) The implementation of such could be "just that simple... print i".  (ed): put it this way.  If inheritance (which meets all your specs) doesn't work, how can I know my arcane macro/template approach works?

Comment: If all you want to do is print `i` and the function gets no information from the class, let the function be free. Unless a function uses `this` the only reason for it to be a member of a class is aesthetics.

Comment: By the way, `i=1;` isn't doing anything. `i` is passed by value so the `i` in the function is a copy of the caller's argument. Setting it to 1 has no effect on the outside world.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's comments,  the reason for the question has todo with using std::variant in c++17.  I find myself repeating code a lot and this would have helped me, but it appear it is not possible.  Std::variant can be used in place of inheritance in some cases (run time polymorphism). S1 and S2 are in a variant<S1,S2>

Comment: As I noted above, I would consider using macros as a fallback.

Comment: edited code to make it more clear as to the need to do some work in the function.

Comment: @GrantRostig In C++, there are often many ways to do things (multi paradigm). Without enough context information, it is hard to make any suggestion as the approach one would use will highly depend on the actual content of the `print` function. One could use templates, polymorphism, free functions, CRTP and more to solve a problem. However, macros should generally be avoided.  Without realistic code and constraints, it is hard to help you.

Comment: @Phil1970, I understand the multiparadym nature of c++ and the question asks if this is possible with templates. In fact the example _now_ does show how simple the situation is.  It appears that what I wanted to do with templates is simply not possible based on the current consenus.  You and others have been kind to point out other approaches, however the question is about templates, without the use of inheritance.  I ended up just copy pasting the function definition for each class. It was just one liner, so copy paste was easy, but looks repetitive. I will likely refactor with inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a template to "inject" a free function to become a member function of each of a number of independent classes. Sorry, just not how things work.

If you wanted to badly enough, you could do this with inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
public:
    bool print() { 
        std::cout << "Printing something\n"; 
        return true; 
   }
};

struct S1 : Base { };

struct S2 : Base { };

int main() {
    S1 s1;
    s1.print();

    S2 s2;
    s2.print();
}
```

But note: inheritance brings a whole host of issues of its own, so it's open to question whether you actually want to do this or not.

Comment: @AndyG: Nothing he's said so far indicates a need/use for CRTP. It would become useful if `print` needed to use things that were defined in S1/S2.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, thank you for your code, however I should have excluded that form of inheritance from the question.  I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: It appears the answer is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
struct function
{
 bool print(int i);
}

struct s1: public function
{
}
```

Now you will be able to use the print function from s1.